# Azure devops users cant see repos even though they have full read/contribute permissions. How could we fix?

Tags: azure-devops

If we add new users to a team, by just adding their email address, the new user can login to the project, but they can't see any of the repos, and don't even see the repos icon on the left (they do see overview, boards, pipelines and artifacts).  These users have been given full access rights to all the repos, i.e. they are in the contributors group. If I look at repositories in the project settings, then find the user, they have all the permissions to all the repos, including read and contribute.

How I can I give them "more" access so they can see and use the git repos?

I have seen similar posts which mention users as being "basic" or "stakeholder", however this is not something I can see or change.

I am full administrator to the project.

Any suggestions?

Interestingly, we used to use git-hub where PRs automatically reflected the latest commit of a branch of a PR.  We migrated to Dev ops a few weeks back, buy cloning the old github repo, setting the remote to devops, and pushing it to devops.  Maybe this is causing the problem.  Now we dont use github at all, and only use the devops copy.

Answer (score 149, accepted):

> They can't see any of the repos, and don't even see the repos icon on
>   the left (they do see overview, boards, pipelines and artifacts

According to your description, these users should only have stakeholder access.

Actually, to use Code you need be qualified with two things:  **Permission** ,  **Access Level**.

Have you checked that User’s Access Level you are? Is that user a Stakeholder in your organization?

[image]

**User with Stakeholder access level, he will not be able to use Azure Repos for your private project.**

You could check this info from Organization Setting-- Users--Access Level

[image]

For more detail concept you could refer our official link:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/security/get-started-stakeholder?view=azure-devops&tabs=agile-process

Please change the user access level to Basic and above, then this user should be able to see and access these repos.

**Note:** To change access level, you must have Project Collection Administrator or organization Owner permissions in Azure DevOps.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Hi, I dont have access to organisational settings.  I am full admin for the project. I can add new users and give them permissions, but they can see everything except the repos.

Comment: Hi John, only with permissions are not enough. You need also make sure they are also with Basic and above access level. Otherwise, they will not be able to access those repos. Only with project admin permission is not enough to change access level, you may have to ask your project collection admin to double check access level for these users.

Comment: +1 because this answer lead to my solution: user's Access Level was set to "Visual Studio Subscriber" and there was an error validating their subscription. As a temporary measure, I set their Access Level to Basic which immediately fixed the issue.

Comment: It works on my end.

Answer (score 6):

try to change user permission to basic
https://jd-bots.com/2021/08/22/fixed-cannot-see-repos-in-azure-devops-with-stakeholder-access/

Comment: Yep, previously it was "Stakeholder" and was not able to view the Repos, as soon as it got changed to "Basic" Repos were visible.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to checking User Access Level in the organization settings and setting it to Basic or higher, as other users suggested, you can check the Azure DevOps Services enabled on the project settings overview and turn on the "Repos" service if not already enabled.
[Project settings overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnoCd.png)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below 3 steps to change user access to Basic

1. Go to Organisation settings -> user ->
   [image]
2. Use edit option

[image]

3. Change access level
   [image]